# How to create a day calendar view as in iphone calendar app

Tags: uitableview, swift3

Using a tableView, I can build the calendar. I am having problems with overlaying a view on top to represent a time interval at a particular time. The code below displays the initial overlay but it does not track the reference cell as the table is scrolled. Appreciate some guidance.See the second screenshot which is from the Apple Calendar App. That is what I want to mimic

```
//
//  CalendarViewController.swift
//
//  Created by Syed Tariq on 01/12/17.
//  Copyright © 2016 com.syedtariq. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

class CalendarViewController: UIViewController,
    UITableViewDelegate,
    UITableViewDataSource
{

    let cellSize = 60
    var tableView: UITableView!
    let cellIdentifier = "cell"


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        do {
            tableView = UITableView(frame: view.frame)
            view.addSubview(tableView)
        }

        do {
            tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier)
            tableView.delegate = self
            tableView.dataSource = self
            tableView.separatorStyle = .none // turn off so the UIView extension can draw the separator line
            tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()



    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 25
    }

    var yCell = CGFloat(0)
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:cellIdentifier, for: indexPath)
        var row = indexPath.row
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

        var post = "AM"
        if row > 12 { row = row - 12; post = "PM" }
        if row == 0 { row = 12; post = "AM"}
        let x = String(format: "%2ld", row)
        cell.textLabel?.text = x + " " + post + " " + String(repeating: "\u{2500}", count: 16)
        showOverlay(indexPath: indexPath, nRef: 5, offset: 0, height: 44.0) // show button cover a cell
        return cell
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    }


    func showOverlay(indexPath: IndexPath, nRef: Int, offset: CGFloat, height: CGFloat) {
        // overlay is a button
        // nRef is the closest cell from which a button is to be placed
        // offset is the top of the button from the top of the nRef cell
        // height is the height of the button based on the time interval to be displayed and calculated based on
        //      height of the cell

        let row = indexPath.row
        let rectOfCellInTableViewCoordinates = tableView.rectForRow(at: indexPath)
        let rectOfCellInSuperviewCoordinates = view.convert(rectOfCellInTableViewCoordinates, to: tableView.superview)
        print("\(row) \(rectOfCellInSuperviewCoordinates.origin.x) \(rectOfCellInSuperviewCoordinates.origin.y)")
        if row == nRef {
            if let z = view.viewWithTag(nRef) as! UIButton?{
                print("z found")
                z.removeFromSuperview()
            }

            let overlayStart = tableView.frame.origin.x
            let overlayWidth = tableView.frame.width
            let frame = CGRect(x: overlayStart, y: rectOfCellInSuperviewCoordinates.origin.y + offset, width: overlayWidth, height: height)
            let overlayButton = UIButton(frame: frame)

            overlayButton.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.5, green: 0.0, blue: 0.5, alpha: 0.3)
            overlayButton.setTitle("Press for more details", for: .normal)
            overlayButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.black, for: .normal)
            overlayButton.layer.cornerRadius = 8
            overlayButton.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
            overlayButton.layer.borderWidth = 2
            overlayButton.tag = 5
            view.addSubview(overlayButton)

        }
    }

}
```

[image: Simulator capture of calendar view]

[image: From Apple Calendar App that I want to mimic]

Answer (score 1):

You are adding the overlay on the main view.

That means when you scroll, all the tableViewCells changes positions in the view, the overlay doesn't know that something changed, and therefor don't change it's position in the view.

**One option:**

Add the overlay as a subview to the tableViewCell. That way the overlay will be in the bounds of the tableViewCell when you scroll.

Comment: It is a good approach but how would I span a cell. For example if I need to span from 12:15 to 1:15 without getting clipped, I would be spanning more than one cell. In my code I had attempted to remove the view from its old position and then re-draw it based on  a re-calculated position of the reference cell In the view coordinate system. That clearly is not working.

Comment: What about putting an overlay on all the cells that are active? If you set the height to be equal to the cell I think it will look likes it's only one overlay

Comment: Both your ideas are good and I am working on a solution. I have reduced the cells to represent 15 minute slots with time labels every hour only. Since the overlay is either a label or a button and contain text, I need to work out scheme to distribute the multiline text so it looks ok. That is the reason I was initially opting for a floating overlay. Unfortunately, I am out of ideas on how to sync it to a particular cell. It can obviously be done as is evident in the Apple Calendar app

Comment: Folowing up on Joakim's suggestion I worked around the problem as follows:

Comment: Hey - please can you share your solution?